# Laravel Nova Self-referential Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-nova

In Laravel, if I want to create a self-referential relationship I can do the following:

```
class Post extends Eloquent
{
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Post', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Post', 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

How can I make a Laravel Nova resource display this connection?

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        Text::make('Autor', 'author'),
        Select::make('Type', 'type')->options([
            'News' => 'news',
            'Update' => 'update',
        ]),
        BelongsToMany::make('Post') // does not work
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve what you want like this:

```
BelongsTo::make('Parent', 'parent', \App\Nova\Post::class),

HasMany::make('Children', 'children', \App\Nova\Post::class),
```

This will allow to choose a parent post when you create or update a post. When you are in the detail page of a post, you can see all its children.

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        Text::make('Author', 'author'),
        Select::make('Type','type')->options([
            'News' => 'news',
            'Update' =>  'update',
        ]),
        BelongsTo::make('Parent', 'parent', \App\Nova\Post::class),
        HasMany::make('Children', 'children', \App\Nova\Post::class),
    ];
}
```

**Note**: Please note that the third param to `BelongsTo::make()` and `HasMany::make()` is a reference to the **Post Resource**, not Post model.

Answer (score 3):

There is another situation, where you will find same issue, if you have parent column name `parent` and also relationship `parent` like

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->string('category');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('parent')->nullable();
```

and 
In model

```
public function parent()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(SELF::class, 'parent');
}
```

It will be unable to recognize the `parent` property and you will face this problem again, in that case, you can change the `relationship name` **or** `column name`, and it will work fine.

Also remember the arguments for Nova `BelongsTo` relationship

Argument 1. Name to display (e.g. `Parent`)

Argument 2. Name of the relationship as used in the model (e.g. `parent`)

Argument 3. The Nova Resource (e.g. `App\Nova\Category`)

Comment: Why should you name a foreign key not with a `_id` postfix?

Comment: @bernhardh  It seems you have a different question, could you please post it as a different question with more details?

Comment: Its more a rhetorical question. Your answer is fixing a problem, which the question creator didn't have and normaly you shouldn't have at all, since its not a good practice to name your foreign key like this.

Comment: @bernhardh I don’t remember the reason behind this naming, but yes the naming conventions should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to have title in your resource that represent the display name

```
class Post extends Resource
{
       public static $title = 'name';
}
```

Comment: this is not valid class.