# Laravel Nova : How to detect in indexQuery if $request is whether from relation or not

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I'm doing exactly what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53595622/laravel-nova-self-referential-relationship)

However, I added this code in my resource

```
public static function indexQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
   
   return $query->doesntHave('parent');
}
```

In order to only show in index, Posts that did not contain parent;

Problem is that this query is also applied in HasMany field;

Children didn't shown on Post Detail

I'm wondering if there's something like `$request->isFromRelation()` that return true if $request is made for relation purpose and then, I can do this :

```
public static function indexQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
   if(!$request->isFromRelation())
        return $query->doesntHave('parent');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found solution for this problem !

There's method `$request->viaRelatonship()` that did the exactly thing I expected ! There's unfortunately no mention of that in documentation!

Anyway, I have now the missing part of my code :

```
public static function indexQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
   if(!$request->viaRelationship())
        return $query->doesntHave('parent');
}
```